# Mongo $cond if expression doesn't work like $match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with documents with a "parent" field.

```
[
      {
        "parent": "P1",
        "tagGroups": [],
        
      },
      {
        "parent": "P1",
        "tagGroups": [
          {
            group: 1,
            tags: {
              tag1: {
                value: true
              },
              tag2: {
                value: "foo"
              },
              
            }
          },
          {
            group: 2,
            tags: {}
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "parent": "P2",
        "tagGroups": [],
        
      }
    ]
```

I want to make request that retrieves all documents with the same parent when at least one match with my criteria: tag1.value = true.

Expected:

```
[
      {
        "parent": "P1",
        "tagGroups": [],

      },
      {
        "parent": "P1",
        "tagGroups": [
          {
            group: 1,
            tags: {
              tag1: {
                value: true
              },
              tag2: {
                value: "foo"
              },

            }
          },
          {
            group: 2,
            tags: {}
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

For that I wanted to use the $cond to flag every document, then group by parent.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/WiIlVeLDrY-

But the "if" part seems to work differently that a $match

https://mongoplayground.net/p/_jcoUHE-aOu

Do you have another efficient way to do that kind of query?

Edit: I can use a lookup stage but I'm afraid of bad performances

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some expected input output

Comment: Hi, the first link shows what i want to do, the expected result is the first 2 documents instead of none.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what you want to achieve, but you expect that your tried code (first link) should be working. You need to use `$in` instead of `$eq` in your query

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$addFields": {
    "match": {
      "$cond": [
        { $in: [ true, "$tagGroups.tags.tag1.value" ] }, 1, 0] }
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$parent",
    "elements": { "$addToSet": "$$ROOT" },
    "elementsMatch": { "$sum": "$match" }
  }
},
{ "$match": { "elementsMatch": { $gt: 0 } }},
{ "$unwind": "$elements"}
)
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ppBlTi9e03U)**

Note : You have asked about the efficient way. Better you need to post expected result

Comment: Thanks! It's working. I edited my post to be more clear. 
I'm trying to use your syntax with the spring boot mongo data api.
Do you think it's the more efficient way ?

Comment: `$unwind` is more expensive. So when you use it, be careful. Otherwise everything fine. Additionally my point of view, if this is a team project, better avoid aggregations and use human readable jpa methods, like findBy...() and java methods. Because writing aggregation may be defer to person to person....

Comment: I can't find another way to make those kind of queries without aggregations. Spring have an elegant fluent api that we can use but it can be tricky for some cases. I avoided a lot of complexity in the example and it doesn't reflect my use cases (the $cond is dynamic).
The big problem I just run into is that the Spring API to build criterias in aggregation is made for the $match stage and it's not compliant with the $cond.

Comment: Then you can feel free to use aggregations with @Aggregation annotation or mongoTemplate

Comment: I worked on it to be able to use the $in (requested in a remove comment).

https://mongoplayground.net/p/pkBARDY3s83